# copy a column with identical function to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to copy a column generated by identity function, identity(1,1), to another table. However, after the process, the whole new column only shows 1.

Is there a way to fix that? thank you

Comment: How are you copying it?

Comment: what is "the process"?  Are copying the column definition (i. e.  trying to make an identity column in the other table?)  or are you trying to copy the data from the original column into the other tables column?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am actually trying to copy  the data from the original column into the other tables column? ex:
original column  
1
2
3
and I hope the new table column has the same numbers
new column 
1
2
3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 CREATE TABLE Dim_Route(RtID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key, Itinerary varchar(50) NOT NULL, ) 
 CREATE TABLE Dim_FlightSchedule(FSID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key, RTID INT, Constraint fk_Route Foreign KEY (RTID) REFERENCES Dim_Route(RtID), )

 insert Dim_Route (Itinerary)
 values 
 ('B'),
 ('C'),
 ('D'),
 ('E'),
 ('F')

insert Dim_FlightSchedule (RTID)
select RTID from Dim_Route
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

> 

The original table:`CREATE TABLE Dim_Route(RtID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
                       Itinerary varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                       )`

The destination table:`CREATE TABLE Dim_FlightSchedule(FSID INT Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
                                RTID INT,
                                Constraint fk_Route Foreign KEY (RTID) REFERENCES 
                                Dim_Route(RtID),
                                )

UPDATE Dim_FlightSchedule
SET Dim_FlightSchedule.RTID = Dim_Route.RTID
FROM Dim_Route`

The RTID in destination table are all 1.
I don't know where I got wrong. Thank you

Comment: Why is there no `WHERE` clause in this query? This is basically telling to take a row from `Dim_Route` and just set that which in this is the first row over and over again. You may want to consider if you want to use some condition here in the `update` statement.